# Using Tokens from an Azure Container Registry to Call the /_tags Endpoint

Tags: docker, authentication, azure-container-registry

**Edit**

I've added an issue on github for this [Azure ACR Repo](https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/676). I think Tokens just came out of Preview and this may be a bug.

**Edit 2**

That github isn't for posting issues... I have to figure out how to create a support ticket which is buried under some custom 'Support Request Contributor' role in the IAM interface. Why is it so hard to report bugs!?

**Original**
I have generated an access token for my Azure Container Registry (ACR) using the Token Menu. I would like to use this access token to call the /_tags endpoint for a specific image in the registry, but I am not sure how to do this.

I can use the token to login using the `docker login` command in powershell, but **the only way I've been able to get the api call to work is by using the admin account credentials**.

[image: Token menu item screen shot]

Can someone provide guidance on how to use the access token to call the /_tags endpoint [Get List - Rest API Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/containerregistry/tag/get-list?tabs=HTTP) for an image in the ACR?

Here is the code I have tried so far, it returns 401 Unauthorized: (Note: I've also tried generating a bearer token using :
`https://myRegistry.azurecr.io/oauth2/token?service=myRegistry.azurecr.io&scope=registry:catalog:*` and using that for authentication. I got the token but the results are the same.)

```
var registryUrl = "https://myRegistry.azurecr.io";

// Set up the HTTP client
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(registryUrl);
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"tokenName:tokenPassword"); //given by the azure token interface
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

// Call the /_tags endpoint to retrieve the list of tags for the image
var imageReference = "my-image";
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"/acr/v1/{imageReference}/_tags");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var imageTagResponse= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DockerImageRegistryResponse>(json);
    foreach (var tag in imageTagResponse.Tags)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(tag.Name);
    }
}
```

The error I get back:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "UNAUTHORIZED",
            "message": "authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.",
            "detail": [
                {
                    "Type": "repository",
                    "Name": "my-image",
                    "Action": "metadata_read"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I thought maybe the "Action" was a clue so I created a custom scope for the Token that explicitly included "metadata_read" but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using tokens with a container registry, you need to authenticate via the oauth/token API of the container registry. Using the API you can create a bearer token to authenticate the token request against the registry.

More details can be found on
https://github.com/Azure/acr/issues/676
and
https://azure.github.io/acr/Token-BasicAuth.html#using-the-token-api

Comment: That did the thing! Thanks for following up and pointing this out. Maybe you could put the instruction directly in this answer to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

**I have tried to list the ACR repository tags using the postman tool as shown below.**

**Step 1:** Create ACR and enable admin credentials and make a note of username and password.
[image]

I have pushed nginx image to ACR with two different tags.

[image]

**Step 2:** Go to the postman tool, use the GET operation and list the image tags as below. Use the authentication model Basic auth and enter username and password from step 1.

[image]

URL used in above screenshot: `https://acr-name.azurecr.io/acr/v1/<repository-name>/_tags`

Comment: I was able to use the Admin credentials, but I am hoping to use the Token credentials instead to limit access to read only.